# Firefox creates ~65 threads for 8 tabs

Tags: linux, firefox, threads

I was looking at the output of `htop` and noticed that Firefox had about 65 threads listed. I only have about 8 tabs going, so I am trying to understand why so many threads have been created and seem to persist. They don't seem to be using my a whole lot of CPU usage or memory usage (about 12%). The command listed for all of them is `/usr/bin/firefox/firefox --new-window`.

How can I go about beginning to understand what is going on here?

Thanks,

UPDATE 1: Currently using Firefox 53.0.3 (64 bit) on Linux

Comment: What version of FF?

Comment: Ah, good question. I've added the version to the question.

Comment: Use `ps -T -p <pid>` to see threads. They’re named!